# Why realloc() is so badly designed?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, realloc

The book **"C++ coding standards 101 Rules,Guidelines, and Best Practices"** by Herb Sutter & Andrei Alexandrescu Item 5 says that

**Give one entity one cohesive responsibility.**

> Focus on one thing at a time: Prefer to give each entity (variable,
>   class, function,namespace, module, library) one well-defined
>   responsibility. As an entity grows, its scope of responsibility
>   naturally increases,but its responsibility should not diverge

The book also gives example of C's realloc() function.

> **In Standard C, realloc is an infamous example of bad design. It has to do too many things: allocate memory if passed NULL, free it if
>   passed a zero size, reallocate it in place if it can, or move memory
>   around if it cannot. It is not easily extensible. It is widely viewed
>   as a short-sighted design failure.**

yes, realloc() can be used to deallocate memory also as we know. see [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-deallocate-memory-without-using-free-in-c/) also.

But my questions are:

1) Why it is badly designed? Why it is designed to perform more than single task?

2) Why it isn't extensible?

Thanks

Comment: What does extensible mean in this context?

Comment: Incidentally, I'm not sure you'll get a useful answer to this.  There are hundreds of examples of imperfectly-designed features in the history of computing.  Why pick this one?

Comment: I would not go so far as saying it's *badly* designed, just that it can do too many things, instead of following the *do only one thing and do it well* principle. As for why, I can only guess it was to allow implementing `malloc()` and `free()` in terms of `realloc()` (but that's only speculation).

Comment: Someone could flag this as Alexandrescu's opinion-based. C++ folks can't stand non-++ way(c)(tm) way too often. Seriously, realloc is a generic interface working with any valid pointer *and* NULL. If they raise that, they should consider malloc/free uselessness on realloc's background instead. Free() is useful as generic one-argument destructor and malloc is just a convenience, someone would note then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Because *checking* whether memory can be allocated and then *actually allocating* it involve some common steps that would need to be re-taken (and thus slower) if done separately.

   Furthermore, combining the free operation with the allocation operation could not only be faster, but it could also allow memory to be allocated that might otherwise not be available in a separate, contiguous location.
   (Imagine allocating 768 MB of memory and then asking for 1 GB on a 1.5 GB machine...)
2. Because it was intended for C, not C++.

Comment: In other words, it's not a *bad* design, it's an inelegant design, justified by the performance benefits.  (Just like zero-copy I/O justifies designed that don't elegantly follow all the ISO layers)

Comment: Regarding combining freeing and allocation, you can add minimum granular-allocation size to the list of benefits, allowing access to memory that is in-reality already-allocated . A minimum 128-byte block size, for example, needs to do near-nothing but update a number when a `realloc` for and initial request of 20 bytes is upped to 50, or 100, etc.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The realloc() function fails to separate a number of important use cases, and consequently ends up not being optimal for any of them.  It's not uncommon, for example, to have code over-allocate storage for objects whose exact total size can be bounded but not known precisely until after they're constructed, and subsequently want to adjust the allocation.  In such cases it would be helpful to have a version of realloc() which would shrink an allocation without moving it (or rendering existing pointers invalid) if possible, or else do nothing.  Realloc can't do that, though.